# onMenuItemClick invoked several times

Tags: android, menuitem

Fast clicking on an action will invoke the listener several times, even though the return value is true - meaning that the event was consumed and should not be invoke
Here's my code:

```
menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // blabla...
        return true;
    }
});
```

Any idea why is the item click event sent twice, even though the return value is true?

Comment: Maybe you have defined another listener for the parent view of `menuItem`?

Comment: Nope. It's only that listener and set once on that specific menuItem. I don't reuse listeners.

Comment: Check if you are accidentally using android:onclick property in your XML menu file.

Comment: The menu is created dynamically in the code only. @Campiador - thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try creating a local boolean as true and put if control inside onMenuItemClick and after click make it false? I guess click won't trigger while it's false. At least you can check if it is caused by your onClick or another listener for the parent view of menuItem as nKn told. My guess is it's because you are fast clicking same button, because of delay on executing onClick you invoke onClick several times by pressing.